# yii2 gridview pjax event

Tags: gridview, yii2, pjax

I would like to run a script after sort gridview where pjax is active. I could not find any event handler after reload of gridview. Is there any proper way of event handler after pjax call and refresh of gridview?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Yii2 Pjax widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html) is just a wrapper of [defunkt/jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) library, so you can view available events list in official Pjax docs in [events section](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events). Seems like you need to use `pjax:success` event:

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
    // Your code goes here ...
});
```

Comment: And a non jquery way?